# how to default argument list construct a class defined within a class with a member with default initilialization?

Tags: c++

The following code fails to compile:

```
struct A {
    struct B {
        int i = 1;
    };
    A(B b = {});
};
```

With the following error from gcc12.2:

```
<source>:5:14: error: could not convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>()' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'A::B'
    6 |     A(B b = {});
      |              ^
      |              |
      |              <brace-enclosed initializer list>
Compiler returned: 1
```

Removing  `= 1` makes it compile. Moving `struct B` definition outside the class also makes it compile. Moving `B b = {}` into `A::A` body also makes it compile.

What is happening? Why? How to fix it?

Comment: fwiw `A(B b = B{});` has a slightly more telling error message: https://godbolt.org/z/cM4ov4Keb